# AMPL Non-Linear least Square

Tags: least-squares, ampl

Could anyone help me to find the error in this AMPL's code for a simple least-square error base on the function:

F(X)=1/1+e^-x

```
param N>=1;# N Number of simulations 
param M>=1;# Number of inputs 

param simulations {1..N};
param training{1..N,1..M};
var W{1..10};

minimize obj: sum{i in simulations , j in 1..4} (1/(1+exp-(W[9]/(1+exp(-
W[j]/(1+exp(-training[i][j]))))+ W[10]/(1+exp(-W[2*j]/(1+exp(-training[i][j]))))))-training[i][5])^2;

'###### DATA
 param N:=6;
 param M:=4;

 param training: 
1   2   3   4   5 :=
1 0.209 0.555 0.644 0.355   0.0
2 0.707 0.450 0.587 0.305   1.0
3 0.579 0.521 0.745 0.394   1.0
4 0.574 0.883 0.211 0.550   1.0
5 0.797 0.055 0.430 0.937   1.0
6 0.782 0.865 0.114 0.317   1.0 ;
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

- is that quote mark before ###### DATA meant to be there?
- You have specified that training has dimension N x M, and your data specifies that N=6, M=4, but you then define training as 6 x 5 and your objective function also refers to column 5.

If that doesn't answer your question, you might want to give more information about what error messages you're getting.